# Simplify trigonometric expression $\frac{1 - \cos A + \cos B - \cos(A + B)}{1 + \cos A - \cos B - \cos(A + B)}$

Tags: trigonometry

> Simplify
>   $$\frac{1 - \cos A + \cos B - \cos(A + B)}{1 + \cos A - \cos B - \cos(A + B)}$$

How can I simplify this trigonometric expression? 
Can you explain it if possible?

Comment: As a start, you could take a look at this [list of trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities).

Comment: Solution on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1261079p6545707.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the identities

$$\cos A -\cos B =-2\sin\frac{A-B}2\sin\frac{A+B}2,\>\>\>\>\>\cos(A + B) = 1-2\sin^2\frac{A + B}2$$

to simplify

$$\frac{1 - \cos A + \cos B - \cos(A + B)}{1 + \cos A - \cos B -  \cos(A + B)}$$
$$=\frac{1 + 2\sin\frac{A-B}2\sin\frac{A+B}2- (1-2\sin^2\frac{A + B}2)}{1 -2\sin\frac{A-B}2\sin\frac{A+B}2 - (1-2\sin^2\frac{A + B}2)}$$
$$=\frac{2\sin\frac{A+B}2(\sin\frac{A-B}2+\sin\frac{A+B}2)}{2\sin\frac{A+B}2(-\sin\frac{A-B}2+\sin\frac{A+B}2)}=\frac{2\sin \frac A2\cos\frac B2}{2\cos\frac A2\sin\frac B2}=\frac{\tan \frac A2}{\tan \frac B2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Writing $A=2x,B=2y$ and using 
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

$$\dfrac{1-\cos2(x+y)}{\cos2x-\cos2y}=\dfrac{2\sin^2(x+y)}{-2\sin(x+y)\sin(x-y)}=\dfrac{\sin(x+y)}{-\sin(x-y)}$$

assuming $\sin(x+y)\ne0$

Use https://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Junior%20Secondary/Componendo%20et%20Dividendo.htm